# Why get 403 Forbidden while click on login

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am working on Spring MVC project. I use Spring Security for secure the url of my project. While i click on login button login succesfully but got error `type=Forbidden, status=403` on `localhost:8092/user/index` url. I think Spring Security interrupt the url.

Here down is code of `Spring Security`:

**CustomUserDetail**

```
public class CustomUserDetail implements UserDetails {
    
    private User user;

    public CustomUserDetail(User user) {
        super();
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        SimpleGrantedAuthority authority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(user.getRole());
        return List.of(authority);
    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {
        return user.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {
        return user.getEmail();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

**UserDetailsServiceImpl**

```
public class UserDetailsServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService{
    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;
    
    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        User user = userRepo.getUserByUserName(username);
        
        if(user == null)
        {
            throw new UsernameNotFoundException(username);
        }
        
        CustomUserDetail customUserDetail = new CustomUserDetail(user);
        
        
        return customUserDetail;
    }
    
}
```

---

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/user/**").hasRole("USER")
        .antMatchers("/**").permitAll()
        .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/user/index");
}
```

Here down is `Controller`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepo userRepo;
    
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/index")
    public String login(Model mdl, Principal principal)
    {
        
        User user = userRepo.getUserByUserName(principal.getName());
        
        mdl.addAttribute("user", user);
        
        return "user/user-dashboard";
    }
}
```

Here down is my `user-dashboard.html` while which is located on `src/main/resources/templates/user`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1> Details of User</h1>
    
    <p th:text="${user.name}"></p>
    <p th:text="${user.email}"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

I got while click on login button that time url is `http://localhost:8092/user/index`

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sat Mar 19 18:16:13 IST 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Forbidden, status=403).
Forbidden
```

Snapshot of database:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should check two things.

1. What is the role data of user in the database?

- I think it should have a prefix "ROLE_" like ROLE_ADMIN in the database.

2. Check the password which should be encrypted and saved in the database.

- Spring security's DaoAuthenticationProvider uses default `PasswordEncoder` made by `PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder()` method.
- So you have to save the encrypted password of user data by using `PasswordEncoderFactories.createDelegatingPasswordEncoder()` instance's encode method. `passwordEncoder.encode(password)`.

Comment: Thankd @junhyunny In my database role is `Role_User`, I changed it to `ROLE_USER` it's worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

while saving in db save it as role_user all caps. spring security compares roles as (role+ hasRole value)==db value.